# SVN post-commit hooks have stopped working after upgrading to FogBugz 7

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, fogbugz, post-commit

Our company have recently upgraded our FogBugz installation to version 7, downloaded the latest post-commit files, and followed the latest instructions on integrating SVN with FogBugz (to get lists of modified files for each case.)

However, I've been unable to get them working. Can anyone shed some light on what i might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Edit:
Thanks Peter, We are running on Fogbugs Windows Server, IIS7 and SVN runs on a seperate server which is runnin Windows Server 2000.

Edit:
I've followed through the troubleshooting guide suggested by Rich (thanks again Rich) and after running "svnlook log -r $REV $REPOS | cscript /path/to/logBugDataSVN.vbs $REV /var/tmp/svnfile $REPOS" get the message "Adding bug info for Bug ID#11118" (which is the correct Bug ID for this particular revision) but no details are being rendered for this case in FogBugz. Am i missing something?

---

EDIT:
Since posting the original question, we've moved our SVN install to another machine on our network (Ubunutu) to free up resources on our Windows server, however we're still having problems integrating.

1. Downloaded the scripts as instructed
2. Moved the scripts to the hooks directory and applied execute permissions on each file ( sudo chmod +x filename )
3. Followed the steps in the walkthrough you linked up to the "see if logBugDataSvn.pl file is working..." section.

I'm seeing the "Adding bug info for Bug ID #11118..." message but nothing is getting added to the case in FogBugz so I decided to dig a little further. My knowledge of Perl is limited but I've got the gist of what the script is doing so I decided to first check the correct arguments are being passed to the script. I joined ARGV and printed to stdout which gave me: [4394 | /var/tmp/svnfile | .]

My understanding (based on the stdout output) is that ARGV[0] is the revision, ARGV[1] is the logfile and ARGV[2] the repo(?) but this doesn't seem to match the code in post-commit. I feel like i must be getting something wrong or am missing something obvious!

Comment: What platform is your server on?

Comment: Why don't you post this on the Fogbugz StackExchange site?? http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Dana, i didn't think of that. In future i'll remember there is seperate section of the site specifically for Fogbugz questions.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, there's a troubleshooting guide here:

http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/blog/post/Debugging-Subversion-Source-Control-Integration.aspx

Comment: Cheers Rich. Will have a look at that and post back if i find a solution on there